# I am using postgres database with golang and i am trying to return connection object but I don't know the return type connection object

Tags: go

```
func (t *DbConnection) Connect() (return type) {
    dbTest, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user = praveen dbname = test_twichblade sslmode = disable")
    return dbTest
}
```

In above example what should be the return type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open function returns (*DB, error), so you should return `*sql.DB`

[func Open(driverName, dataSourceName string) (*DB, error)](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open)

```
func (t *DbConnection) Connect() (*sql.DB) {
    dbTest, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user = praveen dbname = test_twichblade sslmode = disable")
    return dbTest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open
`sql.Open` returns `*DB, error`, so you should return `*sql.DB` in your case.
You can use this information https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/ about `databse/sql` package